# Why doesn't the mobile site tell us how long we have to wait to add a bounty?

Tags: feature-request, questions, bounties, mobile-web

On the full site, if you want to add a bounty to one of your questions that isn't old enough, the "Add a bounty" link is replaced with a link saying:

> Question eligible for bounty in *x* days.

However, on the mobile site, unless our question is over 48(?) hours old, we don't see the "Add a bounty" link.

Can we add the notice that says how long we have to wait to the mobile site?

Comment: There isn't one on the main site either, except possibly for questions you've asked yourself.

Comment: Reworded your title, have a feeling you're grabbing downvotes due to a misinterpretation...

Comment: @djechlin Thank you. That does look better.

Comment: Nah, still downvoting. :)  But a better question.  Just not something useful enough to put on the mobile site; there are hundreds of things I'd want to see first.

Comment: Is this just for your own questions or for any questions? (djechlin's edit might have changed the meaning a bit)

Comment: @doubleDown one of your own.

Comment: @doubleDown yeah I might have swallowed that, I was mostly trying to not make it sound like "gimme an ETA I want this now."  Feel free to make a more correct edit.

Comment: @djechlin, nah, I was thinking, if this question is about bounty on any question (not just on your own question), and on the both regular & mobile site (not just mobile), it'd have been a more relevant (read: upvote-able) question.